Whole system grinds to a near halt, regularly
It's still completely responsive, but the lag is about 1 second from input to reaction.
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            30Gi        15Gi       9.1Gi       522Mi       6.0Gi        14Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B

top/system monitor show nothing unusual, RAM/CPU are not maxed, it's been sitting plugged in this time when it happened, so unlikely battery shenanigans.
I've been reading similar reports where the culprit is SSD. How would I test mine and diagnose whether or not this is the culprit in my situation? I ran the gnome-disks benchmark, and it's excellent, even when chugging (grinding to a near-halt).
Is SSD trouble a reasonable explanation for nearly grinding everything to a halt, and making responsiveness go from however many ms for everything to about 1 second for everything?
I'm now suspicious of firmware. How would I diagnose that?
